# What is wrong with my if parameter syntax of this .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

This is what I've got:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF [%1]==[](
  SET /P server=What url would you like to proxy to? :
  SET /P location=What is the path to your local files? :
)

IF [%1]==[ggp](
  SET server=10.10.10.10
  SET location=c:/Users/Brook/Desktop/hello
)


start chrome.exe localhost:8080/login

call:startServer

:startServer

  node httpdp.js --server %server% --srcpath %location%

  %ifErr% (
    call:startServer
  )

GOTO:EOF
```

When the if conditions are taken out the file runs fine, so something is wrong with my syntax there, but I've no idea.

I would actually like to put the first if condition in an else or default block, after checking if the parameter matches various strings, if anyone knows how to do that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This improves some syntax making it more robust, and stops the subroutine being called twice.  The unknown command is also remed out.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%~1"=="" (
  SET /P server=What url would you like to proxy to? :
  SET /P location=What is the path to your local files? :
)

IF /i "%~1"=="ggp" (
  SET server=10.10.10.10
  SET location=c:\Users\Brook\Desktop\hello
)


start "" chrome.exe localhost:8080/login

call:startServer
goto :EOF

:startServer

  node httpdp.js --server %server% --srcpath %location%

REM unknown command  %ifErr% (  call:startServer )

GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! What does %~1 do? And what is the /i for in line 8?

Comment: `%~1` is the same as `%1` but it removes (one level of) surrounding double quotes if there are any.  This allows the use of quotes or not, in the parameter.  The `/i` makes the test case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it might be able to be improved upon.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF [%1]==[ggp] GOTO ggp

GOTO default

:ggp

SET server=10.10.10.10
SET location=c:/Users/Brook/Desktop/hello
GOTO always

:default

SET /P server=What url would you like to proxy to? :
SET /P location=What is the path to your local files? :
GOTO always

:always

start chrome.exe localhost:8080/login

call:startServer

:startServer

  node httpdp.js --server %server% --srcpath %location%

  %ifErr% (
    call:startServer
  )

GOTO:EOF
```